# After movie clip redirect to subpage

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, movieclip

I need to know how to do a page containing a fullscreen movie clip as a intro for the site, after the movie is finish it will redirect the visitors (without clicking) to a subpage.

Is this possible to do?

No flash, javascript or/and PHP only.

Comment: What are you using to play the movie? HTML5 `video`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just going to assume you're using the `video` element.

```
<video id="somevideo" width="420">
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Now add your event

```
document.getElementById("somevideo").addEventListener('ended',function (e) {
    window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795419/after-movie-clip-redirect-to-subpage";
});
```

You may want to set up some timers or custom handling as this will redirect to the next page the moment your video completes but that's all up to your site spec